# Create ComboBoxes automatically for every paragraph in ppt textbox

Tags: combobox, excel, powerpoint, vba

i am new to VBa and recently encountered the following problem: I copy data (rows) from an excel sheet into powerpoint and I want to make a combobox for every line (so for every row in excel) that i copy. All I could find was how to manually insert comboboxes via the menu in Powerpoint but i want to avoid having to add so many manually. Is there a way to add the comboboxes via VBA code?

```
Here is some of the code I use:

'Loop through each worksheet
 For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

'Create new slide for the data
Set pptSld = pptPre.Slides.Add(Index:=pptPre.Slides.count + 1, Layout:=ppLayoutText)

'Paste the data to the text box of each slide
objSheet.UsedRange.Copy
pptSld.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Paste

'Formatting the text box 2
pptSld.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet = msoTrue
pptSld.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.RelativeSize = 1
pptSld.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 16

    Next objSheet
```

How to continue? Want to define a combo box for each sheet row

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what the code you've posted has to do with adding combo boxes, but here's an example of how to add a combo box and add items to it:

```
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oSl As Slide
Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=168, Top:=24, Width:=192, Height:=24, ClassName:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=msoFalse)
With oSh.OLEFormat.Object
    .AddItem ("This")
    .AddItem ("That")
    .AddItem ("The Other")
End With
```

Comment: the solution is outdated. Have to change 'ClassName' to 'ClassType' and then I get wierd error